# How to pick up unread messages from inbox using uriSMSURI?

Tags: java, sms

My piece of code is here

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
```

To get message I am using

```
 while (cur.moveToNext()) {
          sms +=cur.getString(2) + " : " +
          cur.getString(13).replace("  "," ") + " : " +cur.getString(14) +"\n\n\n";

    }
```

In the above cur.getString(int id) 2nd Index is the sender, 13 index is the message, 14th is the number. I am confused at unread messages.

Answer (score 0):

Here

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html

is description of all columns. You need column "read". If it zero - this is unread message.

How to use:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, null, null, null, null);
if (c!=null) {
    int columnAddress   = c.getColumnIndex("address");
    int columnBody      = c.getColumnIndex("body");
    int columnRead      = c.getColumnIndex("read");

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String smsFrom = c.getString(columnAddress);
        String smsBody = c.getString(columnBody);
        int smsRead = c.getInt(columnRead);
        if (smsRead == 0) {
        // message unread
        } else {
        // message read
        }
    }
}
```